# jasmine unit test for javascript CustomEvent

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

How do I test that a CustomEvent is dispatched in jasmine? When I try running the following code I get the error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CustomEvent".

```
function testCustomEvent() {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', {
    detail: 'foo'
  }));
}

describe('testCustomEvent', function() {
  it('dispatches myCustomEvent', function() {
    var eventSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
    window.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', eventSpy);

    testCustomEvent();

    expect(eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The expectation is not met because eventSpy is called with `{ detail: 'foo'}`

Also, the arguments passed is a new event object containing values of the parameter sent to the Event constructor. So it's never the same object. You will have to enforce a deep partial equal by using a [partial matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_<code>jasmine.objectContaining</code>) if you're using Jasmine 2.0

```
expect(eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
    detail: 'foo'
  }));
```

Or have a [headache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322908/4573999) if you're using a version below 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem with your code is:

You are using `toHaveBeenCalledWith` method instead of `toHaveBeenCalled`.

Former is used for checking two things:

1. Expected Method is called
2. Expected Method is called with correct arguments

Try to run your code [here - Try Jasmine](http://tryjasmine.com/). After replacing `toHaveBeenCalledWith` with `toHaveBeenCalled`.

Note, do not pass any argument to latter.

Comment: This seems to work successfully in tryjasmine.com. However, when I use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine (v0.9.0) I still see the same error - "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CustomEvent".