# Test a function which contains current time in its return value using jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am testing a function which returns an object. Value of one of its key is current time in miliseconds.
How can we test it using jasmine?

```
var fun = function(name,id){
    var obj = {
        name : name,
        id : id,
        createdTime : Date.now()
    }
    return obj;
}

expect(fun("abc",1)).toBe({name:"abc",id:1,createdTime:Date.now()})
```

`Date.now()` returns 2 different values because main function & test case both runs at different time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how specific you need it to be, you could create a range of +-1 second or some similar number with `toBeWithinRange` from the [Jasmine Matchers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-expect) package:

```
expect(createdTime).toBeWithinRange(Date.now() - 1000, Date.now() + 1000)
```

With this method you will have to test the `createdTime` separately from the other test, but that shouldn't be too big of an issue. You just need to assign the return property that you want to the variable `createdTime`.

**Edit**- A similar method with a more clear matcher is using `toBeNear`:

```
expect(createdTime).toBeNear(Date.now(), 2);
```

This will be true if the date assigned to createdTime is within two seconds of the date when the test runs.

**Edit 2**- to exclude object keys when testing, you can follow an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24487384/6456163). This is how you would do it in your case:

```
var joc = jasmine.objectContaining;
expect(fun("abc",1))
.toEqual(joc({
    name:"abc",
    id:1
}));
```

Comment: Is there any way to exclude createdTime key from object while testing object?

Comment: @Vish see the second update to my answer. Should answer your question